# How to create all the possible Sub-Matrices from a large Matrix by shifting exactly one row and one column

Tags: matlab, matrix, submatrix

I am working on a matrix problem where I have an m*n matrix and I want to extract all 5*5 matrices from it by shifting one row and column but I am not able to extract all the 5*5 matrices but only once. Can you help me extract all the matrices?

I am able to extract the using Basic operations but how to extract all the submatrices using a loop

A=[(40 45 50 60 70 80),
 (10 12 15 17 18 20),
 (35 41 57 44 98 78),
 (45 74 11 2  36 78),
 (12 45 79 85 36 45),
  (1  5  8 78 47  3)]

A(1:5,1:5)

example
input:
[(40 45 50 60 70 80),
 (10 12 15 17 18 20),
 (35 41 57 44 98 78),
 (45 74 11 2  36 78),
 (12 45 79 85 36 45),
  (1  5  8 78 47  3)]

output:
[(40 45 50 60 70),            [(45 50 60 70 80),
 (10 12 15 17 18 ),            (12 15 17 18 20),
 (35 41 57 44 98),             (41 57 44 98 78),
 (45 74 11 2  36 ),             (74 11 2  36 78),
 (12 45 79 85 36) ]              (45 78 85 36 45)]

Something like this, I am able to extract the first output but not all the output 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should let you have all the sub matrices in cell array B

```
clear all;
A=[40 45 50 60 70 80; 10 12 15 17 18 20; 35 41 57 44 98 78; 45 74 11 2 36 78; 12 45 79 85 36 45; 1 5 8 78 47 3]
for i=1:size(A,1)-4
    for j=1:size(A,2)-4
        B{i,j}=A(i:i+4,j:j+4)
    end
end
```